# A concern about an integral containing cosine integral function

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

How to prove that

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\mathrm{ci}(px)}{q^2-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2q}\mathrm{si}(pq)$$

The integral was taken from Table of integrals , series and products by Daniel Zwillinger.

It says that the equality holds for $p>0,q>0$. But, I am not sure if that is correct. If I set $p=q=1$ wolframalpha says it is divergent.

The functions are defined as

$$\mathrm{ci}(x) = -\int^\infty_x \frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,dt$$

$$\mathrm{si}(x) = -\int^\infty_x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt$$

I can prove that

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\mathrm{ci}(px)}{q+x}\,dx = -\frac{1}{2}\left\{ \mathrm{si}^2(pq)+\mathrm{ci}^2(pq)\right\}$$

Find the proof [here](http://mathhelpboards.com/calculus-10/ait-cosine-integral-function-18958-new.html).

I am not sure about

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\mathrm{ci}(px)}{q-x}\,dx $$

Comment: If $q\in\mathbb{R}^+$ you are integrating thorugh a singularity ($x=q$) hence something more on the integral has to be specified, for instance that we are considering the principal value. Otherwise, it is simply divergent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Hey Jack thanks for your comment. This is what I was thinking about as well, but the author didn't mention any extra constraints which got me confused. I was able to solve the integral but I got an extra imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For computing the principal values of such integrals, you may exploit the identities:
$$ \mathcal{L}(\text{ci}(x)) = -\frac{\log(1+s^2)}{s^2}\,\qquad \mathcal{L}(\text{si}(x))=\frac{1}{s}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)\tag{1} $$
given by the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and differentiation under the integral sign. For instance, since
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{q+x}\right)=e^{-qs}\tag{2} $$
we have:
$$ J(p,q)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{ci}(px)}{q+x}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{s^2}{p^2}\right)}{2s e^{qs}}\,ds\tag{3}$$
where $\lim_{p\to +\infty}J(p,q)=0$ and
$$ \frac{d}{dp}\,J(p,q)=\frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s e^{-qs}}{s^2+p^2}\,ds=\frac{1}{p}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(pq)-\sin(pq)\text{si}(pq)-\cos(pq)\text{ci}(pq)\right).\tag{4} $$
Integrating with respect to $p$ we get:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{ci}(px)}{q+x}\,dx = -\frac{\text{si}^2(pq)+\text{ci}^2(pq)}{2}\tag{5}$$
as wanted. Let we apply $(1)$ to the first integral in OP's question, too:
$$\text{PV}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{ci}(px)}{q^2-x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{s^2}{p^2}\right)\sinh(qs)}{2qs}\,ds \tag{6}$$
but the RHS is blatantly divergent. If we consider, instead:
$$ J(p,q)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{ci}(px)}{q^2+x^2}\,dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{s^2}{p^2}\right)\text{sinc}(qs)\,ds\tag{7}$$
we have $\lim_{p\to +\infty}J(p,q)=0$ as before and
$$ \frac{d}{dp}J(p,q)=\frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^2\text{sinc}(qs)}{s^2+p^2}\,ds =\frac{\pi}{2pq}e^{-pq}\tag{8}$$
for any $p,q>0$, giving that the LHS of $(7)$ is an exponential integral, $\frac{\pi}{2q}\,\text{Ei}(-pq)$.

Comment: You can complete by 

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{ci}(px)}{q^2+x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2q}\mathrm{Ei}(-pq)$$

Comment: Thanks for sharing this approach I used a slightly different one.